# Very Basic Java program error ("Hello world")

Tags: java

In my program, I want it to output "hello world". It shows an error for the "args" part. The name of my file is "Trial1". Also, I am using eclispe workspace, and dont really understand how i can get a program to play on it. Any ideas? Please help thanks

```
public class Trial1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no issue with code. It has to do with your editor, JDK setup etc.

Comment: thank you! any idea how i can fix that??

Comment: which editor you are trying to use? what are your java settings

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What error do you see and what are you doing before it?

Comment: Is this in a file called `Trial1.java`?  The file name has to match the name of the class (except in a few cases that you might learn about later).

Comment: Hey @User Welcome to Stack Overflow, please copy paste the full error message into your question so that we can help you out.

Comment: @User: are you using BlueJ by any chance? Because it's a weird IDE that bends the rules of what Java usually does.

Comment: i am using eclipse, but am new to it so I am not too sure about how to properly play a program and whatnot. the error i am getting is that "arg is not a proper attribute name" or something along those lines. the file is called "Trial1.java". thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like no error , I already have run with Eclips ,Java 8 [image]

**Note This**  - If you are using Eclips; (you will see error as you see without configure this )

**1.** when you trying to create a class without like below images
(Sometime It doesn't add main method, class to project configuration  ) then you have to add it manually

[image]

**2.** You can verify it Right click the project > Go to   Run As > Click On Run Configurations and you can see details like below image

[image]

Comment: thanks! but when i am adding the class file name, how do i do that? for some reason, i am only able to make a file where i write the name (cannot modify it any further)